# Will this code cause memory leak issue?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Considering the code below, what happens if i use an instance of `Die` class like this:

```
Die d;
d.Roll(20);
d.Roll(15);
d.Roll(30);
```

Should I or should I not free the memory occupied by values before alocating again memory for it? `delete[ ]` before `new`?

**die.h**

```
#ifndef DIE_H
#define DIE_H
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;


class Die
{
private:
    int number;
    int* values;
    int count;
    void roll();
public:
    Die(){srand(static_cast<int>(time(NULL)));number=0;values=NULL;count=0;}
    void Roll(int n);
    int getNumber()const{return number;}
    void printLastValue();
    void printValues();
    ~Die(){delete [] values;}

};

#endif
```

**die.cpp**

```
#include"die.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

void Die::roll()
{

    number=1+rand()%6;
}

void Die::printLastValue()
{
    cout<<number<<endl;
}

void Die::Roll(int n)
{
    count=n;
    values=new int[count];
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        roll();
        values[i]=number;
    }

}
void Die::printValues()
{
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        cout<<values[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include"die.h"
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Die d;
    d.Roll(25);
    d.printValues();
    d.Roll(40);
    d.printValues();
    d.Roll(100);
    d.printValues();
    d.printLastValue();
}
```

Comment: By-definition your program leaks memory unless you match every call to `new` with a corresponding call to `delete` (or `delete[]` for array allocations) **at runtime**. Your runtime can/does invoke successive `new` calls overwriting the same target variables without an intermediate `delete[]`, so yes, this leaks like the Titanic.

Comment: Do yourself a favor, burn your book (or whatever you are currently learning "C++" from) and [get a decent one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/).

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but you should look at using the constructor [initializer list](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) instead of setting all of those values in the body of the constructor. It's one of Scott Meyers 55 ways to improve your C++ program (it is part of Item 4 in Effective C++)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this will cause a memory leak if you call `Roll` multiple times. You should check if values is `NULL` and call `delete []` if it is not.

EDIT:
As commented below, you do not have to check for null, you can safely call delete on a null pointer. Its just a long engrained habit from company standards where I use to work.

You should look into using a `std::vector` instead of the array.  By doing this you will remove the danger of a memory leak and you will no longer need to explicitly define a destructor. You could replace your the `values` with this:

```
std::vector<int> values;
```

Then in your Roll code you could do this:

```
void Die::Roll(int n) {
    count=n;
    values.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        roll();
        values.push_back(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: simply call `delete[]` each time, since delete[] does nothing on null pointers.

Comment: @ipc - I know it is safe to delete null, its just an old habit of checking for null. I also go back and forth between c++ and c# on a daily basis and it is not safe to call "Dispose" on a nullptr

Answer (score 3):

You definitely need to delete them because you are reassigning Die::values, causing memory leaks.

EDIT: in this case it's better to use std::vector than a raw array. Then you don't need to delete anything, but simply call std::vector::clear at the beginning of Die::Roll.

Comment: As well as `values.clear()` and `values.reserve(n)` at the beginning of the `Die::Roll(int)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will leak memory.  When you do

Values = new int [len];

It allocates new memory with the array and points values to the new memory location. The old memory location still contains the old data which needs to be deleted before the new data can be allocated.